# Making every children element to apply parent div class

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple css class:

```
.div-toolbar-content {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

In the HTML code i want to apply this class to every element that is inside of the parent div:

```
<div>
    <svg></svg>
    <p></p>
    <select></select>
    <i></i>
    ....
</div>
```

I have tried putting the class in every element inside the div and it has worked, but is there a way to put the class like in parent div and automatically each element inside the div can apply the class?

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u can use css for that

```
div.main > * {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

and your HTML

```
<div class='main'>
    <svg></svg>
    <p></p>
    <select></select>
    <i></i>
    ....
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to set the styles for the immediate level children's

```
.div-toolbar-content > *{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
},
```

otherwise:

```
.div-toolbar-content * {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```